# Python/Selenium - not sure how to solve for loop problem

Tags: python, selenium, loops, testing, automation

Hi I'm learning python/selenium and practicing automating testcases using a Page Object Model.

I'm trying to automate this page on this demo website https://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/Admin/Category/List

Admin email: admin@yourstore.com
Admin password: admin

In my test case I've added a new category to the table that lists all of the Categories. To test my code is robust, I've decided to add the new category to the end of the table. Therefore you have to go to the last page to view the category that's been added.

here is my CategoriesPage.py file where i call out all the selectors and methods I want to implement on those selectors.

I've tidied it up so it only contains code relevant to the problem.

```
class Categories:
tblrows_css = "tbody>tr"
numOfPages_css = "#categories-grid_paginate > ul > li"

def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver

def getRows(self):
    num_of_rows = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(self.tblrows_css)
    return num_of_rows

def getPages(self):
    num_of_pages = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(self.numOfPages_css)
    return num_of_pages

def pageClick(self, page_num):
    #self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#categories-grid_paginate > ul > li:nth-child(" + str(page_num) + ")").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_link_text(str(page_num)).click()

   def checkList(self, exp_name): #where exp_name is a variable set to 'test123' in the test file 
    flag = False
    num_of_pages = self.getPages()
    print("num of pages is " + str(len(num_of_pages)))
    for page in range(1, len(num_of_pages) - 1):  # don't include arrow buttons, loops through each page until Name is found in table
        self.pageClick(page)
        print("we are on page " + str(page))
        num_of_rows = self.getRows()
        print("num of rows is "+ str(len(num_of_rows)))
        for item in range(1, len(num_of_rows) + 1):
            act_name = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#categories-grid > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + str(item) + ") > td:nth-child(2)").text
            print(item, act_name)
            if exp_name == act_name:
                flag = True
                print("it works")
                break

    return flag
```

So I have 1 small problem and 1 big problem.

The small problem is

```
def pageClick(self, page_num):
#self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#categories-grid_paginate > ul > li:nth-child(" + str(page_num) + ")").click()
self.driver.find_element_by_link_text(str(page_num)).click()
```

I can't get the line I've commented out to work. So I've had to find a work around and use linktext So '1' for page 1, '2' for page 2 etc. However if there was ever a link '1' anywhere else on the page, this method would no longer work.

the error i get using the css_selector is

```
E       selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: element has zero size
E         (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)

venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:242: ElementNotInteractableException
```

The bigger problem is the checkList() method. I've put some print statements to help me figure out what's happening.

I'm trying to loop through all the rows in the 2nd column and get the name of the category(act_name) and see if it matches the exp_name. Once is does it will break out the loop, flag = True and when i assert flag in my test, it will return True and pass. If it doesn't then it will go to page 2 and loop through the table again for all items on page 2 etc.

The problem is when i run this method, it prints out everything on page 1 twice.

```
num of pages is 4
we are on page 1
num of rows is 15
1 Computers
2 Computers >> Desktops
3 Computers >> Notebooks
4 Computers >> Software
5 Electronics
6 Electronics >> Camera & photo
7 Electronics >> Cell phones
8 Electronics >> Others
9 Apparel
10 Apparel >> Shoes
11 Apparel >> Clothing
12 Apparel >> Accessories
13 Digital downloads
14 Books
15 Jewelry
we are on page 2
num of rows is 15
1 Computers
2 Computers >> Desktops
3 Computers >> Notebooks
4 Computers >> Software
5 Electronics
6 Electronics >> Camera & photo
7 Electronics >> Cell phones
8 Electronics >> Others
9 Apparel
10 Apparel >> Shoes
11 Apparel >> Clothing
12 Apparel >> Accessories
13 Digital downloads
14 Books
15 Jewelry
FAILED
```

For some reason when we hit the print statement 'we are on page 2', we are apparently still somehow on page 1. Then it's printing out everything on page 1 again. But when the test fails i can see we hit page 2.

[I can see when the test fails, I have definitely hit page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKSO4.png)

Can anyone figure out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You need to re-get the pagination after the click. (The webelement references are stale after you click...)   The webdriver will return an array of webelement references to the DOM. Once the DOM changes those references will become stale. You may also need a webdriverwait or sleep here.  (If the DOM is updated via javascript...)

Comment: thank you, i will look into what you mean by the webelement references are stale.

Comment: for the pagination links, keep it simple and use IDs.  These would be unique and easily found using a simple xpath.  (in fact all interactable elements should have an id attribute.  It'll make your JS coding and Selenium coding much easier.)

Comment: str(page_num) in your selector is not interpolated by python. look into f-strings. it's used as is by the selector and that's why it can't be found. try making the selector first as a variable, then printing it to see what you made then use the browser inspector to see if you can select that path by hand directly